# What is this doing in Go, looks like a cast

Tags: go

Can someone explain what the following syntax means in Go, specifially:

```
x.([]byte)
```

**I am not sure what this means, is this a cast?  But for what method since it is just after a dot?**

```
func of(x interface{}) ByteView {
    if bytes, ok := x.([]byte); ok {
        return ByteView{b: bytes}
    }
    return ByteView{s: x.(string)}
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/golang/groupcache/blob/master/byteview_test.go#L55

Comment: Check this out https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions

Comment: it's a handy way to get at the concrete type which implements the interface. it's type assertion. the interface{} can accept any type, in this case if that type is []byte then it will be assigned to 'bytes' and 'ok' will indicate that it was that type, i.e. ok is a bool. check this out https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We refer to this as "type assertion."

This is perfectly documented in the [Language Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). In order to have the whole answer here on SO (since it is the whole answer) and not a link-only answer, I will include it the most relevant information from the spec. This is documentation, not my answer...

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression
>
> ```
> x.(T)
> ```
>
> asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of
>   type T. The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.
>
> More precisely, if T is not an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the
>   dynamic type of x is identical to the type T. In this case, T must
>   implement the (interface) type of x; otherwise the type assertion is
>   invalid since it is not possible for x to store a value of type T. If
>   T is an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x
>   implements the interface T.
>
> If the type assertion holds, the value of the expression is the value
>   stored in x and its type is T. If the type assertion is false, a
>   run-time panic occurs. In other words, even though the dynamic type of
>   x is known only at run time, the type of x.(T) is known to be T in a
>   correct program.
>
> ```
> var x interface{} = 7  // x has dynamic type int and value 7 
> i := x.(int)           // i has type int and value 7
>
> type I interface { m() }
> var y I
> s := y.(string)        // illegal: string does not implement I (missing method m) 
> r := y.(io.Reader)     // r has type io.Reader and y must implement both I and io.Reader
> ```
>
> A type assertion used in an assignment or initialization of the special
>   form
>
> ```
> v, ok = x.(T) 
> v, ok := x.(T)
> var v, ok = x.(T)
> ```
>
> yields an additional
>   untyped boolean value. The value of ok is true if the assertion holds.
>   Otherwise it is false and the value of v is the zero value for type T.
>   No run-time panic occurs in this case.

Effective Go is another great resource, which also includes a section on Interface conversions and type assertions:
https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions